# Placing text between two figures

Tags: floats, texstudio

I am just starting in LaTex and I am trying to create a custom titlepage. In our laboratory reports we are asked to have something similar to the image attached. I am having problems aligning the text between the two figures. How can I align it like in the image?

Since I am making the title page from scratch I have two .tex documents like so:

File test_title.tex

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}
\end{document}
```

File title.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./UPRMlogo}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./UPRMlogo}
\end{flushright}

\begin{center}
University of Puerto Rico \\
Mayaguez Campus\\
Mechanical Engineering Department\\
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way, but there are many options. Note the use of `%` characters to prevent spurious spaces from causing overfull `\hbox` warnings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent% just to prevent indentation narrowing the line width for this line
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
\centering
University of Puerto Rico \\
Mayaguez Campus\\
Mechanical Engineering Department
\end{minipage}%
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: If you know Dr. Papadopoulos (at UPRM), say hello to him from me. :-)

Comment: That worked wonders! 

Oh, small world. I haven't taken class with him but I do know him. When I see him around, I'll make sure to let him know! He gives statics and dynamics classes, I took those over 2 years ago, time flies.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote but will make sure to do so once I get to that point. Thanks!

Comment: @user3761290 small world indeed! We worked on [this](http://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00503ED1V01Y201305ENG023) together a few years ago, brought together by a mutual colleague. And you're welcome, glad I could help out. Feel free to leave a comment here if there's anything I can change or explain further.

Comment: That's pretty cool! I do know there is a big debate regarding that class here on campus. Apparently some professors don't apply the topic to engineering and some students think it's wasting their time. 

So I am trying to get the table to be next to the names text but I keep getting some errors including that hbox. I looked up some info on the minipage but can't get it to work properly. I am editing my post to include the new information. Thank you in advance!

Comment: On this site, we try to keep one question per "question" post, because then it's easier to write focused, high-quality answers. So I suggest you roll back your edits to the original question which I've answered here. If you have another question, you should post it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll make sure to follow that as a rule.

Comment: @Paul Gessler  Yes.. Paul Gessler is still around.!!