# Placing text between pictures

Tags: graphics

I'm having the following code

```
Text 1

\begin{figure}[h]
\center{\includegraphics{3}}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
Text 2

\begin{figure}[h]
\center{\includegraphics{1}}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

Text 3

\begin{figure}[h]
\center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{2}}
\caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
```

And I suppose it to output something like on the following scheme

```
Text 1
[Figure 1]
Text 2
[Figure 2]
Text 3
[Figure 3]
```

But instead of it I'm gettimg

```
Text 1
[Figure 1]
Text 2
Text 3
[Figure 2]
[Figure 3]
```

How should I modify my code to get desired result?

**PS.** Yes, I saw the [question with the same title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228308/placing-text-between-two-figures), but that's not my case.

Comment: the only reason to use a `figure` environment is to allow latex to move it, to help with page breaking, so the output you show is not unexpected. Figures are not part of the main text flow they are _floats_ which are separately positioned. You can of course use `\includegraphics` directly in the text if that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You use `\center{\includegraphics{1}}` which (as far as I know) is unknown in LaTeX... so try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}    
Text 1
\begin{figure}[htb]\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.25\hsize]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

Text 2
\begin{figure}[htb]\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.25\hsize]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

Text 3
\begin{figure}[htb]\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.25\hsize]{example-image-c}
\caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

which should give desired result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. But `height=0.25\hsize`is not enough for me. If I put something like `height=0.7\hsize` I get the same wrong result

Comment: @Eugeny89 What you call a “wrong result” is not wrong. It's just the only way LaTeX has to get the text and the figures in good places so as not to spoil the typesetting. If a figure ***must*** go in some place, then it's not a floating object and doesn't have a caption. The caption is exactly what allows for describing the figure in two places: at the reference and under the figure itself.